# How does PDF export handle text alignment?

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format, alignment, rasterize

Context: In digging into [How can I get Mathematica to not mis-align plot labels when exporting to pdf without rasterizing the text?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162942/how-can-i-get-mathematica-to-not-mis-align-plot-labels-when-exporting-to-pdf-wit/163458#163458), and getting an answer to [How does pdf export compute the size of the bounding box of Inset?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163457/how-does-pdf-export-compute-the-size-of-the-bounding-box-of-inset), I have come to discover that PNG export agrees with *Mathematica* rendering but disagrees with PDF export about the size of text, and that this disagreement is very pronounced for font size 12, but much smaller for font size 16.

I created the following example to demonstrate the disagreement:

```
ClearAll[NextSize, MakeBound, BoxChars, MakeG];
TextSize[text_] := 
  TextSize[text] = Rasterize[Text[text], "RasterSize"];
NextSize[opts___][{_, _, str_}, 
   ch_] := {If[str == "", 0, TextSize[Style[str, opts]][[1]]], ch, 
   str <> ch};
MakeBound[y_, opts___][{xmin_, ch_, _}] := {EdgeForm[Thin], White, 
   Rectangle[Offset[{xmin, 0}, {0, y}], 
    Offset[{xmin, 0} + TextSize[Style[ch, opts]], {0, y}]]};
BoxChars[Style[text_, opts___], y_] := 
  Join[Flatten[
    Map[MakeBound[y, opts], 
     Drop[FoldList[NextSize[opts], {0, "", ""}, Characters[text]],1]]], 
     {Black, Text[Style[text, opts], {0, y}, {-1, -1}]}];
MakeG[nmax_, fs_] := 
  Graphics[Flatten[
    Table[BoxChars[
      Style[StringJoin @@ Table["a", Mod[n, 2, 1]*10], fs], 
      n/nmax], {n, 1, nmax}]]];
Rasterize[p16 = MakeG[10, 16]]
Rasterize[p12 = MakeG[10, 12]]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "foo-p16.pdf"}], p16]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "foo-p16.png"}], p16]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "foo-p12.pdf"}], p12]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "foo-p12.png"}], p12]
```

In *Mathematica* as well as in PNG export, we get each character in a box:

`foo-p12.png`:

[image: foo-p12.png]

`foo-p16.png`:

[image: foo-p16.png]

However, in PDF export, the boxes do not align with the characters.  At font-size 12, this is quite apparent after 6 or so characters, and by 20 characters, the text fits in only 19 boxes.  At font-size 16, it is only barely apparent after 20 characters.

`foo-p12.pdf`:

[image: foo-p12.pdf]

`foo-p16.pdf`:

[image: foo-p16.pdf]

If it's relevant, this is on *Mathematica* 11.2.0.0 on Windows 10 64-bit.

My question is: What is going on here?

Comment: I don't see the misalignment on MacBook Pro with 11.1.1. Do you still have a problem if you print? It might be a screen rendering issue.

Comment: Tangentially relevant: "[Monospaced fonts are not monospaced](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10801/280)." *Mathematica* has serious problems with character positioning both in the FrontEnd and in `Export`, unfortunately.

Comment: You shouldn't trust `Rasterize` in determining the size of anything, especially when it is a text string. `Rasterize` is known to be off by 1-2 pixels even in situations when it deals with [exact objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96072/280). The case of textual primitives is [especially painful](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/280).

Comment: @Themis it shows up when I use pdf2png.com to convert the pdf to a png, and inspect the pixels of the png, so I don't think it's a screen rendering issue.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Replacing `Rasterize[..., "RasterSize"]` with `ImageDimensions[ImageCrop[Graphics[...]]]` shows a very similar issue; does `ImageDiminsions` have the same problem?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov In any case, because I am aligning each box based on the raster size of the *entire string up to that point*, being consistently off by 1-2 pixels on an entire object shouldn't impact much of anything. Certainly, it should not accumulate as I add more characters. That is, if I have *n* "a"s followed by a "b", and I render that, and then I offset a box by the width of *n* "a"s, it seems odd that things would line up perfectly in the display in Mathematica, but be off in the pdf export by an amount that grows with *n*. (Though I guess monospaced fonts not being monospaced might do)

Comment: `ImageCrop` uses `Rasterize` under the hood, it can't be avoided. `Export` to PostScript formats (PDF, EPS) seems to use it's own conversion rules which are independent from `Rasterize`. "Certainly, it should not accumulate as I add more characters." - Yes, the more identical characters, the lesser should be error.

Comment: If you wish to add a frame around each character, it is possible to achieve with `Grid`: `Grid[{Characters["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]},Spacings->0,Frame->All,FrameStyle->AbsoluteThickness[0.01]]`. But this approach will destroy the inter-character spacing in non-monospaced fonts (which is [already wrong even for monospaced fonts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10801/280), so it isn't a big deal).

Comment: Thanks, but the box-around-each-character is actually just a contrived example for pushing on the bit I didn't understand (that rasterize / image dimensions gets more and more off from pdf export as the length of the string grows); my actual issue that I'm solving is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162942/how-can-i-get-mathematica-to-not-mis-align-plot-labels-when-exporting-to-pdf-wit/163458#163458